# How to keep image in its original place while rotating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an image in my HTML document:

```
<img id="img1" src="C:\Html\img1.jpg" alt="my-image" width="150" height="150" Style="position:relative;left:600;top:45;"`>
```

I want this image to rotate on button click , I'm able to do this but the image is moving from its position to default position.

```
function Test() {
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        angle+=3;
        $("#img1").rotate(angle);
    }, 50);
}
```

I want the image to be in the place where it first loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use jQuery rotate, but you can set the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property in my version:

```
$('#img1').click(function () {
    'use strict';

    var $this = $(this),
        angle = 0,
        v;

    setInterval(function () {
        angle += 3;
        v = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"

        $this.css({
            '-webkit-transform': v,
            '-moz-transform': v,
            '-ms-transform': v,
            transform: v
        });
    }, 50);
});
```

Of course you don't have to target `this`, as in your case you would use `#img1` and the event handler would be on the `button`.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VHAa/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a "center" when you use that plugin.

```
$("#img1").rotate({angle: angle, center: ["50%", "50%"]});
```

[It's right there in the documentation.](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation#center)

Comment: Center is used to change the image center, I changed 50% to 5%, I found the center of image is changed,from that center it is rotating. What i want is , to move the position of image but not image center.

Comment: The "center" option is used to change the **center of rotation**. I don't know what you mean by "move the position of image but not image center".